# If $\alpha$, $\beta$ are roots of the equations $x^{2}+px+q=0$ and $x^{2n}+p^{n}x^{n}+q^{n}=0$, where $n$ is an even integer...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $\alpha$, $\beta$ are roots of the equations $x^{2}+px+q=0$ and $x^{2n}+p^{n}x^{n}+q^{n}=0$, where $n$ is an even integer, show that $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, $\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$ are roots of $x^{n}+1+\left(x+1\right)^{n}=0$.

By Vieta's relation I got $\alpha+\beta=-p$ and $\alpha\beta=q$ from the first equation, and if we take the second equation as a quadratic in $x^{n}$, then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of this equation$\implies\alpha+\beta=-p^{n}$ and $\alpha\beta=q^{n}$. However, in the solution which I got on the internet, it stated the following:

> $\alpha$, $\beta$ are roots of $x^{2n}+p^{n}x^{n}+q^{n}=0\implies\alpha^{n}+\beta^{n}=-p^{n}$ and $\alpha^{n}\beta^{n}=q^{n}$.

Could someone help me understand why they have mentioned $\alpha^{n}+\beta^{n}=-p^{n}$ and not $\alpha+\beta=-p^{n}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\alpha^n$ and $\beta^n$ are roots of $X^2 + p^n X + q^n = 0$.

Comment: When you "take the second equations as a quadratic in $X = x^n$", you forgot to account for the roots being $\alpha^n , \beta^n$.

Comment: @SeewooLee how did you get that?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Try to plug them directly: $(\alpha^n)^2 + p^n(\alpha^n) + q^n = \alpha^{2n} + p^n \alpha^n + q^n = ...$

Comment: @CalvinLin Haven't they mentioned that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the second equation? How did the roots come about to be $\alpha^{n}$ and $\beta^{n}$?

Comment: They are 2 out of $2n$ roots of the second equation. When you "take the second equation as a quadratic", that gives us a third equation. What are the roots of $X^2 + p^n X + q^n = 0 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the equation $x^2 +px +q=0 \implies \alpha +\beta=-p$
and
$\alpha^n$ and $\beta^n$ are roots of the equation $y^{2}+p^n y+q^n=0 \implies \alpha^n +\beta^n=-p^n$.

Therefore,

**Case 1:**

Let $x=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$

$$x^{n}+1+\left(x+1\right)^{n} =\frac{\alpha^n}{\beta^n}+1+ \left({\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\beta}} \right)^n =\frac{\alpha^n +\beta^n + (\alpha+\beta)^n}{\beta^n}=\frac{-p^n+(-p)^n}{\beta^n}= \frac{-p^n+p^n}{\beta^n}=0 $$

**Case 2:**

Let $x=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$
$$x^{n}+1+\left(x+1\right)^{n} =\frac{\beta^n}{\alpha^n}+1+ \left({\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha}} \right)^n=\frac{\alpha^n +\beta^n + (\alpha+\beta)^n}{\alpha^n}=\frac{-p^n+(-p)^n}{\alpha^n}= \frac{-p^n+p^n}{\alpha^n}=0 $$